# Django error: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)

Tags: django, django-views

```
def play(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        number_of_records = Puzzles.objects.count()
        random_index = int(random.random()*number_of_records)+1
        rand_puzz = Puzzles.objects.get(id = random_index).puzzle
        solution = eval(rand_puzz)
        if 'a' in request.GET:
            a = request.GET['a']
                if a == request.GET['solution']:
                    message = "correct"
                    return render(request, 'play.html',                           {'rand_puzz':rand_puzz,'solution':solution,'message':message})
                else:
                    message = "incorrect"
                    return render(request, 'play.html', {'rand_puzz':rand_puzz,'solution':solution,'message':message})

        else:
            message = 'play the game'
            return render(request, 'play.html', {'rand_puzz':rand_puzz,'solution':solution,'message':message})
    else:
        return render_to_response('home.html')
```

So I'm getting this error:invalid syntax (, line 1). The page works initially, then this will happen. I'm completely baffled by what this error means and any help would be appreciated

Comment: probably is that eval that has something wrong to evaluate, could you please post an example of rand_puzz that triggers that error?

Comment: `if a == request.GET['solution']` and the following block is incorrectly indented. Could you post the whole traceback of the error?

Comment: Here's the traceback:   http://dpaste.com/1342343/

Comment: So rand_puzz puzzle would contain something like: 2 + 2

Comment: This doesn't solve your problem, but the proper way to get a random record from the database is `rand_puzz = Puzzles.objects.order_by('?').only('puzzle')[0]`. The way you are doing now, if you ever delete a record; you may run into a situation where the random index picked doesn't exist in the database; which will lead to a `Puzzles.DoesNotExist` exception. In addition, you should also use `if request.GET.get('a') and request.GET.get('a') ==  request.GET.get('solution'):`

Answer (score 0):

Find out what string is causing the exception.

```
 try:
      solution = eval(rand_puzz)
 except SyntaxError:
      print rand_puzz
```